# The ngIf troubles with hiding content

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have some code that I'm trying to get to work. We are running Angular 5. I am trying to write the code in a way that uses ngIf to determine if a search by state option isn't there, give them a search by zipcode. I have that working with a toggle on one instance of this application.

```html
<div *ngIf="!browseMyState" class="form-control form-control__search-bar">
    <label for="" [innerHTML]="settings.locationLabel || settings.zipcodeLabel"></label>
    <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'locationError': showLocationError }" name="location" aria-label="Enter Location" [placeholder]="settings.locationPlaceholder || settings.zipcodePlaceholder" [(ngModel)]="locationValue" (change)="onLocationChange($event)">
    <div *ngIf="showEmptyLocationError !== undefined" class="locationErrorValue" [ngClass]="{'visible': showLocationError }">Please enter a valid location</div>
</div>
```

However, we are using the same set of code to run another instance of the application that is a bit more complicated. I want to hide the search by location on the other instance of the application and not show it at all if certain fields aren't defined, but I'm getting stuck. I can run the above code and it does what I need it to. I can also run the below code and get what I need on this other application, but I can't successfully run both at the same time.

```html
<div *ngIf="zipcodePlaceholder !== undefined" class="form-control form-control__search-bar">
    <label for="" [innerHTML]="settings.locationLabel || settings.zipcodeLabel"></label>
    <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'locationError': showLocationError }" name="location" aria-label="Enter Location" [placeholder]="settings.locationPlaceholder || settings.zipcodePlaceholder" [(ngModel)]="locationValue" (change)="onLocationChange($event)">
    <div *ngIf="showEmptyLocationError !== undefined" class="locationErrorValue" [ngClass]="{'visible': showLocationError }">Please enter a valid location</div>
</div>
```

When I run that code though, it takes away the location search on the other instance of the application but I also can't run them at the same time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is between both instances of the application some more? If it is ok for the application to know about the type of instance it is you can just use && for some checks to only work on one of them (by checking the condition && if it is the right instance).